# Python Regular Expressions Pattern Matching issues

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm in a group project working on a homework assignment, and I'm trying to use my partners python script to gather input from a text file. I haven't worked with Python in a while and never with the *import re* set.

Essentially I'm loading data from a text file with a repeated pattern...The pattern is as follows.

```
SAMPLE INPUT 1:
3 1 1
1
3
SAMPLE OUTPUT 1:
3

SAMPLE INPUT 2:
4 2 2
2 3
1 4
SAMPLE OUTPUT 2:
4

SAMPLE INPUT 3:
8 2 2
1 8
5 4
SAMPLE OUTPUT 3:
5
```

The script attempts to gather the data with the re.findall(pattern,string,flags).

```
with open("dp.txt","r") as f:
        file = f.read() #bad if taking in big file
        #the code stops executing here..I assume because no pattern is matched
        for m in re.findall("SAMPLE INPUT (\d):\n(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)\n(.*)\n(.*)\nSAMPLE OUTPUT (\d):\n(\d+)\n",file):
```

I hate to ask for a solution on a Golden Platter, but at this point the only thing holding me back from implementing my algorithm is the stupid pattern matching. I'm hoping for a fresh pair of (Python experienced) eyes that could tell me why the re.findall() isn't matching the .txt file

Thanks for any advice you can throw my way, as a C programmer I'm finding the documentation on these Python imports to be insufficient..but maybe that's just a personal problem :)

Comment: Please explain what your expected output is supposed to be. Also, this regex does match the samples in the file for me. Make sure you are using the correct newline characters, and make sure your file has a newline at the end of the file (the regex expects it to capture the last sample)

Comment: Are you sure that your input file only uses line feed as the line break? Windows machines tend to use \r\n for example.

Comment: The problem seemed to lie with Python 3.4.2..Moral of the story is use Python 2.7...Thanks for the suggestions guys!

Answer (score 0):

I find out your understanding about regex and re.findall() are mostly correct. The problem is all about `file = f.read()`, here file is a built-in class.

On the other hand, the official documentation absolutely is the best guide, while you can type help(file),help(re.findall) under REPL.

One more thing,

```
with open("dp.txt","r") as f:
        s = f.read()
#you better start the new line out of the with-block coz it releases the opening file
for m in re.findall("SAMPLE INPUT (\d):\n(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)\n(.*)\n(.*)\nSAMPLE OUTPUT (\d):\n(\d+)\n",s):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# load the regex module
import re

# make a method bound to a precompiled regex (can use it like a function)
get_samples = re.compile(
    r"SAMPLE INPUT (\d+):\n(.*?)\nSAMPLE OUTPUT \1:\n(.*?)(?:\n\n|$)",
    re.S     # make . match \n
).findall

# This regex looks for text like:
#
# SAMPLE INPUT {a number}:
# {data}
# SAMPLE OUTPUT {the same number}:
# {data}
# {a blank line OR end of file}
#

# load the data file
with open("myfile.txt") as inf:
    txt = inf.read()

# grab the data
data = get_samples(txt)
```

which on the given data results in

```
# data
[
    ('1', '3 1 1\n1\n3', '3'),
    ('2', '4 2 2\n2 3\n1 4', '4'),
    ('3', '8 2 2\n1 8\n5 4', '5')
]
```

The data elements need further parsing, like

```
def ints(line):
    return [int(i) for i in line.split()]

def int_block(block):
    return [ints(line) for line in block.split("\n")]

data = [(int(a), int_block(b), ints(c)) for a,b,c in data]
```

which gives

```
# data
[
    (1,   [[3, 1, 1], [1],    [3]   ],   [3]),
    (2,   [[4, 2, 2], [2, 3], [1, 4]],   [4]),
    (3,   [[8, 2, 2], [1, 8], [5, 4]],   [5])
]
```